# reading data from stm32 on esp8266

Tags: c, uart, arduino-esp8266

im sending via uart data from stm32 like this:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %f;", (int32_t)ir_average, (int32_t)red_average, (int32_t)dcFilterIRresult, (int32_t)dcFilterRedresult, (int32_t)chebyshevResult2, (int32_t)elipticResult2, (int32_t)wyjscie, (int32_t)bpm_up, (int32_t)fftbmp, (int32_t)currentSaO2Value, (int32_t)spo2Calib, temp); 
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, buffer, 100, 1000);
```

how should i read it from esp8266 side in arduino ide?
maybe i should do it differently?
i wanted to send a packet od data and split it after reading full packet on esp8266

Comment: You should transmit using the actual string length (the return value from `sprintf`) not the buffer size.

Comment: thats right but its still for testing ( i dont know how many data ill send to esp) but dont know how to read for example 100 buffer at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in arduino you read using Serial.read() which returns char. Form a string out of it.

```
    String resp;
    char   _char;
    while(Serial.available()){
        _char =  Serial.read();
        resp += _char;
    }
```

to convert it to int use [.toInt()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/toint/)

to separate individual numbers use [.indexOf](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/indexof/)

Comment: then if i want to separate it i would send (A%dB%d) then do A=data.indexOf("A") ? and then what?

Comment: Take each data by locating the sapce and updatin the string

input_string = input_string.substring(input_string.indexOf(' ') + 1);
int32_t ir_average= (int32_t)(input_string.substring(0,input_string.indexOf(',')).toInt());

input_string = input_string.substring(input_string.indexOf(' ') + 1);
int32_t red_average= (int32_t )(input_string.substring(0,input_string.indexOf(',')).toInt());

Comment: input_string.indexOf(' '))

Comment: input_string.substring(input_string.indexOf(' ') + 1); 
int32_t ir_average= (int32_t)(input_string.substring(0,input_string.indexOf(',')).toInt());
second ',' or " " for string in question?

Comment: by your advice i did it like this and it works:
in stm32:
sprintf(buffer, "<A%dB%dC%dD%dE%dF%dG%dH%dI%dJ%fK%fL>", (int32_t)x, x, x, x,...)
in arduino:
if(incoming=='<')
          {
          Data+=incoming;
          while(incoming!='>')
            {
            incoming=Serial.read();
            Data+=incoming;
            }
          Data = Data.substring(Data.indexOf('A') + 1); 
          x= (int32_t)(Data.substring(0,Data.indexOf('B')).toInt());

Answer (score -1):

To read bytes from the UART in arduino IDE: Serial.read() (in a loop) or Serial.ReadString().

Generally speaking, prefer using snprintf to sprintf to avoid buffer overflows.